# firewalld port forwarding breaks outbound traffic on that port

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, firewalld, gateway

I'm using a Linux computer as a gateway/firewall between the wider network and a few servers.

```
WAN -> [ 192.x | GATEWAY (Linux) | 10.x ]  -> [ 10.0.0.100 | SERVER (Linux) ]
```

This configuration works fine as a gateway. Downstream nodes can hit the Internet fine, and I can port forward requests for `80` at the gateway to `8000` on the sever with `firewall-cmd`.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.0.0.100:toport=8000
```

**However**, once I run that command and port forwarding starts, the server (`10.0.0.100`) is no longer able to reach back out to the `WAN` on port `80`. That's a problem because it means the server can't reach any HTTP traffic on the internet.

The server can `curl` any Internet resource *except* if it's on port `80` while that forwarding rule is in place.

The gateway only has one physical NIC and it is in the `external` zone, which enables masquerading.

```
gateway:$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:1b:40:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe1b:409e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:1b:40:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```bsh
gateway:$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 onlink
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2
```

I'm probably missing some fundamental tenant about networking that's preventing me from understanding this issue.

My assumption is that the forwarding rule makes it so *all* port 80 traffic (inbound or outbound) is getting mangled, when really I only want inbound traffic from 80 to get forwarded to 8000 for my server.

Is the network configuration possibly wrong? Or is there something about how I'm using `firewalld` that's invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `iptables` or `firewalld` can be used in my scenario to port forward to specific machines on the downstream subnet, but I could not figure out how to get it working.

This may not be ideal, but my workaround was to create a systemd service on my `gateway` machine that uses `socat` to forward traffic on a specific port to a specific IP.

This is the script that gets run on my `gateway` to forward ports `80` and `443` to `10.0.0.100`.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-port=80/tcp
socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork TCP4:10.0.0.100:80 &
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-port=443/tcp
socat TCP4-LISTEN:443,fork TCP4:10.0.0.100:443 &
wait
```